# ./containerlaunch.sh: line 6: update-ca-certificates: command not found

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

UPDATE: Apparently, the error happens when Microsoft Azure AD is enabled.

My Docker image is based on Debian slim. (UPDATE: Even images based on Alpine have this error)

```
FROM node:18-slim
...

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes ca-certificates
```

Even with the `ca-certificates` I am getting the error below:

```
2023-05-17T11:33:13.888836835Z ./containerlaunch.sh: line 6: update-ca-certificates: command not found
2023-05-17T11:33:13.898826553Z Updated CA certificates
2023-05-17T11:50:14.463204566Z ./containerlaunch.sh: line 6: update-ca-certificates: command not found
2023-05-17T11:50:14.486848458Z Updated CA certificates
2023-05-17T11:50:54.115862067Z ./containerlaunch.sh: line 6: update-ca-certificates: command not found
2023-05-17T11:50:54.119680808Z Updated CA certificates
```

Locally works fine; only in Azure App Services I have got this error. What can be?

Comment: can you share more details on ./containerlaunch.sh contents?

Comment: I don’t own it, it is from Azure

Comment: Have u tried adding the command `update-ca-certificates` to your Dockerfile-
`FROM node:18-slim` `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes ca-certificates`
`RUN update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Yes. This definitely is not related to the  container

Comment: "error happens when Microsoft Azure AD is enabled" – what does it mean exactly? enabled where?

Comment: Enabled on App Service

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's a problem with the certificate installed in the base image. Run the following individually:

1. Verify that your date / time are set correctly
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Run `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`

If that doesn't work, do the following:

1. Disable certificate: add `Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }` to `/etc/apt/conf.d/`
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Run `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`
4. Re-enable certificate verification by removing `Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }`

This should work. I hope it helps!

Comment: Nope. Note related to the base image, it is a Azure issue.